# Why Error: ValueError: Empty training data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have got a training dataset of 1,000 images but while compiling my code, I came across this error;
Error: ValueError: Empty training data?

What's the possible solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is no validation or test dataset in your directory. Ensure you have data in your validation directory.

Comment: Ok, you guys are quite obvious :D